# Windows 7: "enter" network password using compiled .exe file and bypass the "Enter password network" dialog

Tags: networking, password-protection

I have a question about accessing some network resources with password protect.

I already have access to network using my private login/password. Every time opening network resource on clean Windows system I have to enter login/password to corresponding fields.

My question is about the C# function/library that could help to use my login/password in .exe file to bypass the "Enter password network" dialog.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym7zz.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WNetAddConnection3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for that. Be aware, though, that this means you will be saving your password to a file. It will be readable in the source file and in the resulting executable.